# CORs error in react app when trying to fetch data from API, but works in Postman

Tags: reactjs, postman

I have a react app and am trying to make a post request to a remote API. Here is the relevant code:

```
const App = () => {
  const [logData, setLogData] = useState([])

  const fetchUserData = () => {
    const username = 'logging-user';
    const password = 'password';
    const url = 'okstate';
    const authHeader = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
    const requestOptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': authHeader
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ username, password, url })
        };
      fetch('url/get_logs', requestOptions)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
        setLogData(data)
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserData()
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  )
```

In the browser I am getting a CORs error:

```
Access to fetch at 'url/get_logs' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I know these are super common errors for this sort of request, but before you downvote me, I'm just trying to understand these better. I know the solution is the allow this on the server, but I don't control the server. My question is, I can make the same request in Postman and it returns data as it should; I have the same headers and auth configured in Postman. So is that consistent? I though a request is a request (or a post in the this case) and it should not matter what the origin is.

Answer (score 0):

A little bird gave me this answer, which I think makes sense and is what I was looking for:

The reason you can make the request from Postman without encountering a CORS error is because Postman is not a browser. It is an HTTP client tool that operates outside the constraints of the browser's security policies, including CORS restrictions.

Postman allows you to make HTTP requests directly from your machine's network interface, bypassing the same-origin policy and other security measures enforced by browsers. It does not enforce CORS restrictions, so you can freely send requests to any domain from Postman.

On the other hand, when you make a request from your React app running in a browser, the browser enforces the security policies, including CORS. The browser sends an additional preflight OPTIONS request to the server to check if the actual request (POST) is allowed from the origin. The server needs to respond with appropriate CORS headers to indicate that it allows requests from your app's domain. If the server doesn't include the necessary headers or explicitly allows requests only from specific origins, the browser blocks the request due to CORS restrictions.